# Should I disable wuauclt.exe on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, updates

I've came across an old laptop using Windows XP, so I am trying to boost its start time a bit. Among other processes, wuauclt.exe (stands for Windows Update AutoUpdate Client) seems to be active during the loading of the system. After a quick google search I found that it's responsible for checking/installing windows updates. 
Because Windows XP is not updated since 2014, is it ok to disable this functionality as it probably has no effect anymore but the system still automatically runs it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think it's a good idea to disable it. However, I'd suggest to create a restore point before doing this, just to be safe.

Comment: OP can just disable it as a service. no need to create a restore point.